# Wait cursor in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone

Is there an easy way to display a wait animation in the iPhone sdk. I have a screen that will take a few seconds to load, and I'd like to give the user some feedback that something is happening. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

or

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```

will do the trick!

**edit:** Found this one in an older project, client requested an indicator with better visibility:

```
-(void)invokeMegaAnnoyingPopup
{
    self.megaAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please wait..."
        message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil
        otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];

    [self.megaAlert show];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
        initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

    indicator.center = CGPointMake(self.megaAlert.bounds.size.width / 2,
                                   self.megaAlert.bounds.size.height - 45);
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [self.megaAlert addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator release];
}

-(void)dismissMegaAnnoyingPopup
{
    [self.megaAlert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    self.megaAlert = nil;
}
```

You would of course need a `UIAlertView *megaAlert;` defined in your class.