# cursor circle for waiting on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, xcode4

I'm checking how to make the user wait on a screen that make a request on internet.

I already use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

to show a little circle bar, but I want to block the application (disallow the possibility to the user to navigate trough the app)

I checked [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285685/wait-cursor-in-an-iphone-app) but I don't know how launch those methods!

Thank to read/help me!

Answer (score 3):

Use
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
when you start activity indicator
and

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents]; 
when you end activity indicator

Comment: OK, but can Y put a sort of grey screen on of to show that the app is really running ??? and to advice to the user that the app isn't bugging?